# Can you use filepond’s “server” to connect to MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, server, filepond

I want to send a picture to my MongoDB back-end through filepond, is this possible? I’m using react and node aswell.
Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we work on the policy that the user must show an attempt before getting assistance. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.